# Superset - Stacked Bar chart - want to display value as % of total of entire Bar

Tags: apache-superset

Pl see screen shot
I am building dashboards and charts in Apache Superset

Can we display total value (sum of all stacks) above bar
Can we display % of total value in each stack

Y axis will need to be absolute value for the dimension

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mzp1.png)